# Regex that matches a string that contains a specific character a certain number of times

Tags: regex, powershell

How to write a regular expression in PowerShell that matched "|" 4 times? My example data below"

```
| W|100003574 |  3|
| W|100003574 |  3| 89|
```

So the expected output will be

```
| W|100003574 |  3|
```

Here the code I use but it didn't work.

```
$getdata | Select-String -Pattern '^([|]{4})$' -allmatches
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would only match a line that was exactly 4 pipes all by themselves which is not what you want.

```
$getData | Where-Object{[regex]::matches($_,"\|").count -eq 4}
```

I am only using regex here since it makes for a very terse solution. I still needed to escape the pipe as it is a special character in regex. This will return all lines that have exactly 4 pipe characters.

**Another solution that still uses regex but not the .Net method**

Convert the string to a char array and attempt to match the pipe character. `-match` here will return an array of all matches so we still use `.Count`

```
$getData | Where-Object{([char[]]$_ -match "\|").Count -eq 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .Net regex to get the result

```
([regex]::matches($getdata, "^(\|[ \w]+){3}\|$", "Multiline") | %{$_.value})
```